# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to follow the example under @Configuration & @Bean Annotations section from link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm, and I got the following exception:

```
Dec 31, 2018 2:59:33 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2dda6444: startup date [Mon Dec 31 14:59:33 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
```

I am using java 1.8, spring 3.2.1. Thanks for your help.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
   @Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}

package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }
   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}

package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext ctx = 
         new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);

      HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
      helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
      helloWorld.getMessage();
   }
}
```

It failed on new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class) of the MainApp.java

Comment: can you update the code and better to explain at which step you got this

Comment: try by giving complete path `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldConfig.class);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It did show security issues when loading the class. I tried to include the package name, the error did not go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use Spring 4.1.6, as specified in the tutorial.

I reproduced your error using `spring-framework-3.2.1.RELEASE-dist.zip` but the Hello World app ran fine for me using `spring-framework-4.1.6.RELEASE-dist.zip`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the latest version, and that worked perfect.